# SQL query to pull unique records

Tags: sql

I have 3 columns in my sql database

```
Cateogory    Subcategory 1  Subcategory 2
----------   -------------  -------------
Operations    others        production
Operations    others        production
SupplyChain   others        sales    
SupplyChain   others        sales 
Operations    others        distribution
Operations    others        production
SupplyChain   external      sales
```

I can have same category, but different values for sub category 1 and 2.

I need to write a query with list of unique categories subcategory 1 and subcategory 2.

How can I achieve this ?

Sample output will be

```
Cateogory    Subcategory 1  Subcategory 2

Operations    others        production
SupplyChain   others        sales    
Operations    others        distribution
```

Comment: It would help greatly if you could improve your question so we can actually understand. For example, show samples of current data and desired output.

Comment: MsSQL or MySQL? can simply do select distinct(Cateogory + "," + Subcategory1 + "," + Subcategory2) as distinct_cat from table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` keyword

```
SELECT DISTINCT  Cateogory, Subcategory 1, Subcategory 2
FROM your_table
```

Comment: I will need to pull other column as well.. .hw can select ? SELECT *   
FROM ( 
select distinct Category  ,[Sub Category 1],[Sub Category 2] from table
where source = 'A');